# Url for PageData mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how can i get my url for PageData?, The current `pagedata url is PageData["LogoUrl"] = "/images/logo.png"`; but i need to change the url to `@imageSrc` where the picture is stored in is:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(logo.PicImgData, 0, logo.PicImgData.Length);
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
var imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imageBase64);

PageData["LogoUrl"] = "/images/logo.png";
//ive tried with PageData["LogoUrl"] = "@imageSrc"; but it doesnt work
```

Comment: `PageData["LogoUrl"] = imageSrc;`?

Comment: Nvm ty anyways, i realized that pagdata couldnt get the property because it was outside the if-statement, now it works